# Use adb shell to disable spam logs with priority ERROR

Tags: android, shell, android-logcat

I'm stuck using a closed-source library whose developers decided it would be wise to log every operation, no matter how trivial, with priority ERROR.  Many of these operations occur in continuous loops.  I can filter the output in logcat, but there is so much that relevant messages disappear faster than I can read them in DDMS's logcat viewer.

So far I've tried the following:

```
stop
setprop <tag> 7 //it looks like setprop expects the pri level as a string, so this won't
start           //work

stop
setprop <tag> INFO //I think this allows for INFO pri logs and above, so that doesn't
start              //help

logcat <tag>:S //should suppress all logs from the given tag, but has no effect on
               //logs in logcat and starts cloning logcat output to the shell for some
               //reason
logcat *:S //tried just to see if it would work -- it printed the beginning of new
           //empty log session to the shell and then never returned control of the shell.
           //logcat output in Eclipse was unaffected
```

as root, but none of these suppressed the ERROR spam.  Do I need to specify a target VM running on the device to which the above commands should apply or are they system-wide?  If I do need to specify a VM, how do I do so? The only official documentation I've found that's at all relevant is [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html) for logcat filtering.  Are there any comprehensive setprop manuals around, preferably from Google?

**Main Question:** Is there any way to disable/suppress all logs with a given tag, even if the priority level is ERROR?

[image: it can't be turned off... but it does break easily]

Answer (score 1):

One way is to filter out the messages from the command line and store them in an error file.
You can try the following command:

> adb logcat *:W | grep -v "^E"* > error.log

.

> *:W

The filter expression displays all log messages with priority level "warning" and higher on all tags

> grep -v "^E"*

filters out all the Error messages.

> *> error.log*

Saves all these messages in a file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: interesting, but this doesn't appear to keep the error logs from being printed in DDMS logcat viewer.

Comment: You can use the regular expression in the log_tag field for the filter.. For Example to filter out "Error" you can use _(?!Error\b)\b\w+_ Refer this link for some visual cues   http://jmlinnik.blogspot.ca/2011/11/android-logcat-filter-in-eclipse.html

Comment: unfortunately, filtering in logcat doesn't help much because the real problem is that the logcat buffer is being quickly filled; this results in actual errors and similarly important log messages being overwritten before I can read them. The only workaround I've found so far is to clone logcat output to a persistent file in NVM with a customizable size using the command $adb shell "logcat -r 20480 -n 1 -f '/mnt/sdcard/logcatdump.txt'".  That allows me to browse logs at my leisure, but is cumbersome.